# What is -ffreestanding option in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, freestanding

What is `ffreestanding` in gcc ? What is it used for ? I came across the following :

```
gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
```

and do not understand, what does it mean exactly.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681304/compile-for-freestanding-environment-with-gcc

Answer (score 94, accepted):

A `freestanding` environment is one in which the standard library may not exist, and program startup may not necessarily be at "main". The option `-ffreestanding` directs the compiler to *not* assume that standard functions have their usual definition.

By default, GCC will act as the compiler for a hosted implementation, defining `__STDC_HOSTED__` as 1 and presuming that when the names of ISO C functions are used, they have the semantics defined in the standard. To make it act as a conforming freestanding implementation for a freestanding environment, use the option `-ffreestanding`. It will then define `__STDC_HOSTED__` to 0, and not make assumptions about the meanings of function names from the standard library.

For more Info, [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) link may help.

Comment: @Dayalrai I used `-ffreestanding` option with `arm-non-eabi-gcc` : `arm-non-eabi-gcc -g -O0 -ffreestanding ......`, but I still get main symbol by calling `nm` command  `U main`  which generate me debugging error with `gdb` : `Function "main" not defined`. how can I avoid generating this `main`symbol

Comment: Typically, `-ffreestanding` is used for compiling kernels. Besides, it is rarely used to compile applications which would directly interact with the kernel without making the use of a library. Normal applications would not use `-ffreestanding`.

Comment: I am running Dhrystone benchmark on Cortex-M7 and inclusion of  `-ffreestanding` as compiler option  causes drop in DMIPS/MHz number. So, it's better to avoid it in such cases.

Comment: As @Nee notes, compiling with `-ffreestanding` may well result in decreased performance of the compiled code. The reason for this is that **the `-ffreestanding` option implicitly enables `-fno-builtin`**, which means that you cannot benefit from the automatic substitution of any standard library function calls with GCC built-ins, such as `memcpy` being compiled directly into an inline copy loop. The [merits of this design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713375) aside, it is definitely something that one should be aware of when evaluating the use of `-ffreestanding`.