# Setting a memory using memset on a platform having limited resources?

Tags: c

I need to clear a chunk of memory (32-bit `float`s) to zero, and I use `my_set()`:

```
static inline void my_set(float *dst, float v, int n)
{
    while (n-- > 0)
        *(dst++) = v;
}
```

```
#define MY_SIZE 1024 

int main()
{
    float my_mem[MY_SIZE];

    my_set(&my_mem, 0.0f, MY_SIZE)

}
```

Should I use [memset()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) instead? Will it perform better on a platform with limited resources? Will [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) optimize `my_set` to use `memset`?

Comment: I would turn it around: `memset()` is the default choice. Do you have any reason to introduce `my_set()`?

Comment: @nielsen I'd guess it's more convenient and less error-prone, since you don't have to multiply the length by `sizeof(float)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use memset() instead?

Yes.

> Will it perform better on a platform with limited resources?

Yes. Or it will at least not perform worse.

> Will GCC optimize my_set to use memset?

Yes, no, maybe. When compiling with `-ffreestanding` (embedded systems target) it tries not to include any library calls and then discards any `memset` calls. Otherwise in PC-like environments, the machine code seems to boil down to a `memset` call.

Please note that setting something to zero explicitly or setting it to a value will generate very different machine code.

`memset` and similar library functions are optimized to perform well on the data width of the CPU. Which is not necessarily the same as the data width of a float, typically 32 bit.

Comment: To clarify further: [What is -ffreestanding option in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692428/what-is-ffreestanding-option-in-gcc)

Answer (score 4):

<s>Seems that it will: https://godbolt.org/z/hP8jr1odP</s>

Seems that it depends on architecture and array size, but will usually be optimized to `memset`: https://godbolt.org/z/YqnrEfPGY

```c
#define MY_SIZE 1024 * 1024

static inline void my_set(float *dst, float v, int n)
{
    while (n-- > 0)
        *(dst++) = v;
}

float my_mem[MY_SIZE];

int main()
{
    my_set(my_mem, 0.0f, MY_SIZE);
}
```

| Array size \ Architecture | x86_64 | arm | arm64 | risc-v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 KiB | loop | memset | memset | memset |
| 1 MiB | memset | memset | memset | memset |

Still, I'd trust the compiler to know what's best and not worry too much.

Comment: Don't benchmark C code with a C++ compiler...