# GCC C/C++ Compiler missing some "files", whose seems to have weird names

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

From some random moment and for some unknown reason, my compiler stopped working. It lets me know about errors, warnings, etc., but i still get this error:

```
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cp: missing destination file operand after 'build/obj'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
/home/vhajsman/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/14.0.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find build/obj/*: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont get it. Can someone please help me? Here is my build script, but i am sure it is correct, because compiler can not even compile simple hello world program (which is 100% correct) without throwing these errors.

```bash
SOURCES_CPP=$(find -type f -name "*.cpp")
SOURCES_C=$(find -type f -name "*.c")
SOURCES_ASM=$(find -type f -name "*.s")

CFLAGS=" -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -lgcc -I ./src/ -I ./src/libs/libc"

i686-elf-as $SOURCES_ASM 
i686-elf-gcc $CFLAGS $SOURCES_C  -std=gnu99
i686-elf-g++ $CFLAGS $SOURCES_CPP -fno-rtti

OBJFILES=$(find -type f -name "*.out")
cp $OBJFILES "build/obj"
rm -f $OBJFILES

i686-elf-g++ -T src/linker.ld -o build/bin/cubebox.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib build/obj/* -lgcc
```

Can someone, please explain and help me? Thanks!

Comment: According to your error message, you're missing the C++ standard library, the C++ runtime, and many more files. Maybe you should consider re-install your compiler

Comment: minimal reproduceable problem. is ASM stuff working fine? then remove it we dont need to see it.. only show the minimal amount of stuff needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

whats your linux distro ?
Remove the ffreestanding option, its to not search for the standard lib.

([What is -ffreestanding option in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692428/what-is-ffreestanding-option-in-gcc))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).