# Why doesn't arm-none-eabi-gcc search for my custom _start symbol?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I am compiling the below code with "**-nostdlib**". My understanding was that arm-none-eabi-gcc will not use the **_start in "crt0.o"** but it will **use the user defined _start**. For this I was expecting to create a start.S file and put the _start symbol.

But if I compile the below shown code without the _start symbol defined from my side, I am not getting any warning. I was expecting "warning: cannot find entry symbol _start;"

Questions:

1) Why am I not getting the warning ? From where did GCC get the _start symbol ?

2) If gcc got the _start symbol from a file from somewhere, could you let me know how to ask GCC to use the _start from my start.S file ?

> $ cat test.c

```
int main()
{
    volatile int i=0;
    i = i+1;

    return 0;
}
```

> $ cat linker.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 20K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

> $ arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -nostdlib -T linker.ld test.c -o test.o
>
> $ arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
>
> arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529         >(release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 224288]

Answer (score 3):

Compile *and link* with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v -Wall -Werror -O2`.... to understand what the compiler is doing (and which [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) it is using; that `crt0` probably has a `_start` calling your `main`, also `_start` might be the default entry point for your linker)

Notice that `-nostdlib` is related to the (lack of)  [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library); perhaps you want to compile in a freestanding environment (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681304/compile-for-freestanding-environment-with-gcc)), then [use `-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) (and in that case `main` has no particular meaning, you need to define your starting function[s], and no standard C functions like `malloc` or `printf` are available except perhaps `setjmp`).

Read the C99 standard [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) draft. It explains what freestanding means in §5.1.2.1

Comment: -v option in GCC didn't give me any information about which crt0 is used. I searched for crt0, crt1, *.S files and also for _start. Also with -ffreestanding, I am not getting the warning.

Comment: Did you *link* with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v -Wall -Werror -O2` ?

Comment: Yes I link. Because at the end I have the linker file defined and also test.o is my final output. In freestanding mode, which is then the "starting function" ?

Comment: You should read the standard. Freestanding C has no *standard* notion of *starting function*, it is *implementation specific* (and could be *user* specific)

Comment: Ok. But if I don't want the freestanding mode, do you know from where the compiler get _start ? I am not able to find any info from -v